# How to get the text of div class?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

#Days

```
        try:
            days2.append(link2.find_all('div',{'class':'list-card variable-text list-card-img-overlay'}).text)
        except Exception:
            days2.append('N/A')
```

#Views

```
        try:
            views.append(link2.find_all('div',{'class':'Text-c11n-8-53-2__sc-aiai24-0 duChdW'}[2]).text)
        except Exception:
            views.append('N/A')
```

https://www.zillow.com/manhattan-new-york-ny-10023/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%2210023%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-73.9951494604187%2C%22east%22%3A-73.9682415395813%2C%22south%22%3A40.763770638446054%2C%22north%22%3A40.7898340773195%7D%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A61637%2C%22regionType%22%3A7%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A15%7D
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MauB.png)

[image]

[image]

keep getting N/A instead of 2hours and 88views

Comment: find_all returns a list, which has no text attribute.

Comment: how to fix it then?

Comment: You can use find. If you would share the html in text, rather then a screenshot, your question would be easier to answer.

Comment: I shared the website above.

Comment: https://www.zillow.com/manhattan-new-york-ny-10023/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%2210023%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-73.9951494604187%2C%22east%22%3A-73.9682415395813%2C%22south%22%3A40.763770638446054%2C%22north%22%3A40.7898340773195%7D%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A61637%2C%22regionType%22%3A7%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A15%7D

Comment: I can see that, but you should try to narrow your question down. Post the relevant html code in text and show what your expected output is.

Comment: <div class="hdp__sc-qe1dn6-1 jqZymu"><div class="Text-c11n-8-53-2__sc-aiai24-0 iBdXNb">Time on Zillow</div><div class="Text-c11n-8-53-2__sc-aiai24-0 duChdW">36 minutes</div></div>
output should be 36 minutes

<div class="Text-c11n-8-53-2__sc-aiai24-0 duChdW">26</div>

output should be 26

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the time on Zillow data you mentioned in the comments, you could search for divs with the appropriate class name.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="hdp__sc-qe1dn6-1 jqZymu"><div class="Text-c11n-8-53-2__sc-aiai24-0 iBdXNb">Time on Zillow</div><div class="Text-c11n-8-53-2__sc-aiai24-0 duChdW">36 minutes</div></div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
time = soup.find('div', class_="Text-c11n-8-53-2__sc-aiai24-0 duChdW")
print(time.text)
# 36 minutes
```